# Python: Share interactive plot with non-Python users (offline)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly, bokeh, interactive

Every now and then I need to share plots I created in Python with non-Python users. So far, I've been using PNGs exported from Matplotlib (static), or HTMLs created with Plotly (interactive) to this end.

However, now I'd like to add some dropdown menus to my interactive plot. As an example, say I have data stored in a nested dict, like

```
data = {'country1': {'city1': {'month': [<some list>], 'temperature': [<some list>]},
                     'city2': {'month': [<some list>], 'temperature': [<some list>]}},
        'country2': {'city3': {'month': [<some list>], 'temperature': [<some list>]},
                     'city4': {'month': [<some list>], 'temperature': [<some list>]},
                     'city5': {'month': [<some list>], 'temperature': [<some list>]}}}
```

What I'd like to do is to plot 'temperature' as a function of 'month', based on the values selected in two dropdown menus:

1. First dropdown menu to select country
2. Contents of second dropdown menu should update based on selected country (i.e. city1 and city2 for country1, city3, city4 and city5 for country2)

As far as I understood, dropdown menus can be created using Plotly, but to create a dynamic dropdown list like my second one, it looks like I need Dash in addition to Plotly.

My problem is that, to share an app created with Dash with a non-Python user, the app needs to reside somewhere online (e.g. free: Heroku, PythonAnywhere.com, paid: Dash Enterprise). As I often work with confidential data, I'd rather not store this data online.

**So now my question is:** are there other packages in Python that can do what I want, without the need to store things online?

An online search left me rather overwhelmed; the possibilities seem to be numerous (see e.g. [this link](https://mode.com/blog/python-interactive-plot-libraries/)). Would Bokeh be an option for me? What would you recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download plotly graphs to an offline html file. Anyone you send that file to can open the graph in a browser and interact with it.

https://plotly.com/python/interactive-html-export/

Comment: Thanks, that's great! Do you know whether Plotly can also do dynamic dropdown menus (without using Dash)?

Comment: Yes you can do drop down menus while retaining the interactive functionality in an offline setting. 
https://plotly.com/python/dropdowns/

Comment: Cool, and what about dynamic dropdown menus (i.e. contents of second dropdown depend on value in first dropdown)?

Comment: That depends on whether the options are static.  Specifically does choosing option 1 always reveal option A,B, and C.  This is possible. But if option A,B, and C were dependent not only on option 1, but also option 2 from another figure then this requires dash because that is more than just a dictionary, which is essentially how the plotly dropdown menus are built.

Comment: Brilliant, yes, my options are static; all data comes from one dictionary (or json file, if need be). It looks like I'll need to dive deeper into the details of Plotly, and ignore all references to Dash. Good thing it's almost weekend ;-) Thanks a million for your help!